# How to use SOLR in ASP.NET Web application (3.5 Framework)? Please describe best way to do it

Tags: asp.net, solr

I want to use `SOLR` search platform from the `Apache Lucene` project in my `ASP.NET` web application.

The basic purpose is to utilise `SOLR` for search from database for my entity related property.

Let me be specific.

I have three tables in Database and all of them have 7-10 columns with thousands of data.

E.g `Table #1 TBLEmployee` (Containes refernce from `TBLEmployeMentType`,`TBLEmployeeDept`) and `Table #2 EmploymentType` and `Table #3 is TBLEmployeeDept`.

In short two tables are reffered in one table. And all of them are having too many data.

Now I want to utilise `SOLR` for purpose of search based on employee `name`, `emailid`, `employementtype` etc.

Please suggest way to do it, as my client want me to use it rather than database Stored Procedures.

P.S :- if you have any doubt in my question please ping me on post so that i can explain in details.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please narrow it down to something more specific. Otherwise it sounds like you want us to do your job for free.

Comment: Well all i want to know is way to impliment SOLR in my .NET application.

Simple question is :- how can i use SOLR in my .NET application?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i use SOLR in my .NET application?

Solr has a HTTP interface, so you can use it by issuing HTTP requests against it. You can do this with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), or using [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) or [SolrSharp](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/).

> my client want me to use it rather than database Stored Procedures.

Solr is **not** a relational database, it's not meant to replace a relational database, it's meant to be used as a full-text search engine. For some applications you *can* use Solr instead of a relational database but you need to understand that they're not the same thing at all.

> I have three tables in Database and...

Here are some articles on designing a Solr schema and mapping a database to Solr:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign
- http://blog.neofreko.com/index.php/2008/08/20/tips-on-designing-solr-schema/